# Drag marker to any place (mountain, sea...)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want to drag a marker to any place possible (seas, mountains...) but when I try it keeps moving the marker to the nearest street.

My code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "dragend", function(event){
                    mkpoint = marker.getPosition();
                    map.panTo(mkpoint);
                    geocodePosition(mkpoint);
                });
```

function geocodePosition(pos){

```
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode( { latLng: pos}, function(results, status){
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results.length) {
            if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {               

                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
                direccion = results[0];
                point = new google.maps.LatLng(direccion.geometry.location.lat(),direccion.geometry.location.lng());
                map.setCenter(point);

                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: point,
                    map: map,
                    draggable:true,                 
                    title: "Prueba"
                });
```

(* geocoder, map, point, direccion, mkpoint and marker are all global variables)

I don't know if something is missing or if I'm doing something wrong. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simply remove the call of `geocodePosition(mkpoint)` .

Comment: Hi Dr.Molle! Yes, not doing the geocodePosition call will make the marker stay but I make this call to update the lat, long, address and other things. I suppose that making this update is where the mistake is, but I don't know where.

Comment: There is no mistake, but this function performs a reverse geocoding, it **tries to find an address** for the given location(this address must not be located at the exact LatLng)...when such an adress will be found which is not exact at the input-LatLng the marker will be moved to the different location.

Comment: I see. So there are places (mountains, seas) where Google Maps returns and address that is not in the same exact coordinates, right? If so, is there a way to update only the lat/long and make the marker stay in the position where you drop it? (I don't know if I'm making any sense, sorry). Anyway, many thanks for the answers Dr.Molle! :)

Comment: Update the  lat/long where? Currently you use the LatLng only to set the new position of the marker...what will move the marker.

Comment: I found where I was doing the mistake. I was initializing the marker with point being the lat and long from the address, so it was always leaving the marker on a known address. I've changed that to reflect the lat/long from the dragend event and now the marker sits wherever you drop it. Thanks for all the help! :)